# Has anyone encountered the error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I'm on my development server, where I've produced a react app, which works perfectly, albeit, with the console-logged error,

> "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a
> response was received."

When I deployed the app through git to netlify, the single-page app will not display at all. It gives me the error above as well as:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined."

I've tried disabling all extensions in Chrome to no avail. The problem does not exist in Firefox. Does anyone know how to fix this in Chrome?

Comment: The second error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined."` seems to be an error on your code. I am having the same first error as you though (`"Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."`) and was searching for an answer, won't find it here tho.
Just to add more details: I created a app using `npx create-react-app react-app`, run it on localhost using `npm start`, then on chrome when I check dev tools I see this error. Would be nice to know why and how to fix it. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it!